# Minify while keeping function names with webpack and babel

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to stop the minification happening between babel and webpack from renaming my functions.  I came across [this](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/babel-minify-webpack-plugin/) but apparently don't have the right options set up.

Here's my webpack config file.  What do I need to change to make it keep my function names?

```
const path = require('path');
const MinifyPlugin = require('babel-minify-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        translate: ["@babel/polyfill", "./Scripts/es6/translate.js"],
        setupForm: ["./Scripts/es6/setupForm.js"],
        prelimForm: ["./Scripts/es6/prelimForm.js"],
        recruiters: ["./Scripts/es6/recruiters.js"]
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './Scripts/build'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new MinifyPlugin({
            "keepFnName": true
        }, {})
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [terser-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin) job to minify the html, you can pass to it `keep_fnames: false`.

```
module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          keep_fnames: true,
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: To be clear, what needs to be passed is `keep_fnames: true,` in order to keep the function names

Answer (score 0):

You can ask Babel to drop some old browser compatibility with this configuration in your `babel.config / babelrc`:

```
presets: [
  ['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {browsers: ['> 2%']}}]
]
```

> More informations about `targets` : https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#targets
>
> Dropped browser compatibilities : https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_function_name